# How to configure JavaMailSender on Wildfly14

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly-10

I'm wanna configure Mail Sender on Wildfly14. Could anyone tell me the way to configure it from start to end please.

I successfully configure on application.property, but I wanna store that host, username and password on wildfly instead of application.property.

Here is the code that I was configure on application.property

```
spring.mail.host=xxx
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.username=xxx
spring.mail.password=xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Add all the required properties under system-properties tag in standalone.xml like :

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="spring.mail.host" value=""/>
        <property name="spring.mail.port" value=""/>
        <property name="spring.mail.protocol" value=""/>
        <property name="spring.mail.username" value=""/>
        <property name="spring.mail.password" value=""/>
</system-properties>
```

Similarly, you can add more properties as per your requirement.